# Compiled Emacs but Shared Object files Missing Unless LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable correctly set

Tags: install, compile

I compiled Emacs to run on Redhat Linux. Since I wanted to compile it with `--with-native-compilation` flag, I had to install Redhat's developer tools to get libgccjit. These tools are installed in /opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root. An enable script is provided which modifies the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

I ran `configure` like:

`./configure --with-x --with-native-compilation --with-json --with-imagemagick`

After compilation running make and install, I noticed two things:

1. I was able to launch Emacs from my bash terminal, *but only after* running the `enable` script (i.e. sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the correct directory). In a fresh terminal or after logging out and logging back in, launching Emacs gives the error:

`emacs: error while loading shared libraries: libgccjit.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

2. Launching Emacs from the Applications menu fails.

Are there `configure` script arguments that will make emacs point to the right shared object directory without it being dependent on an environment variable? I guess that would be the `rpath`. Would tis be the `--libexecdir` or `--includeddir` or `--libdir` flags to `configure`?